# How to get Java version instead of HotSpot VM version in MANIFEST.MF file?

Tags: java, manifest, jvm-hotspot

I have an Ant script to compile source code and create a jar file. Some additional attributes have been appended to the MANIFEST.MF file. However, the `Created-By` attribute shows the HotSpot VM version:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.2-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: wang
```

But what I expect is the java version such as 1.6.0_27. How to achieve this?

**Update:**

My JAVA_HOME points to JDK. Here is the output of command "java -version":

```
H:\cad>java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Does your JAVA_HOME or whatever ant uses, point to HotSpot VM? Try changing it to point to a JDK instead.

Comment: @adarshr I think it is pointing to JDK. See my update in question.

Comment: Does using the verbose flag, `ant -v -f build.xml` validate this?

Comment: @adarshr:- did you get an answer for the problem, I'm facing the same thing.. There is a custom solution that I explicitly provide manifest file. But did you get some other solution.

Comment: @108 I did not ask the question!

Comment: @adarshr:- oops! sorry